# How can I print backgrounds with the background-image: fixed CSS property?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I've been doing a lot of searching and I can't find anyone asking this question. I'm trying to write a nicely styled resume in HTML (and print it to PDF), and have highlighted some things with CSS backgrounds. I can keep most of these backgrounds by selecting the right printing option in Chrome.

However, there is one background I can't print. I wanted multiple

tags to share the same gradient background, so I found a solution (detailed [here](https://multiple.js.org/)) that uses the following CSS styling on each

element:

```
.skill{
            white-space: nowrap;

            /* Gradient background */
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 2px 5px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(120, 60%, 75%), hsl(120, 33%, 90%));
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: 100%;

            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
```

Even with `-webkit-print-color-adjust`, Chrome doesn't display these backgrounds. If I set `background-attachment` to anything else, it shows up in the print, but it no longer has the look I want.

Any ideas for a workaround to this? I don't care about compatibility with any specific browser, I just want to be able to print it as a PDF!

Edit: Thanks for the quick responses! Just for clarity, my page doesn't have any javaScript running, only HTML and CSS. I don't want to post the full code since it has personal information, but if it is absolutely necessary I can take out all of that stuff and leave the layout and styling. I made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/75ctha8d/2/), where, interestingly enough, if I try to print the page, I CAN see the gradient background... Here are some screenshots: [printing my resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6q6s.png) vs [viewing my resume in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaGs4.png). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjRPC.png) is what I see when I try to print the fiddle (which is what I want! I'm pretty sure I could get that beige background with some more webkit-print stuff).

Will try out WkHTMLtoPDF and report on how that works as well.

Edit 2: WkHTMLtoPDF didn't work for me either. I got an "unknown error" with exit code 1. I moved on to the suggestion to just use JS and background-position, and that worked well! I removed the `background-attachment` property and used the following JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
            var skills = document.getElementsByClassName("skill");
            Array.from(skills).forEach(function(item, index){
                item.setAttribute("style", "background-position: -" + item.offsetLeft + "px -" + item.offsetTop + "px");
            })
        };
```

While perhaps not the most elegant solution, I don't mind because I'm doing this more for myself than anything. Any non-JS solutions would be awesome as well, but this is good enough for me. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you create a snippet or fiddle that demonstrates the issue? Or include some of your HTML? I can't seem to reproduce this behavior. If I create `div` elements with the `skill` class, and CTRL+P in Chrome, the background shows up in the preview.

Comment: After looking at multiple.js I suspect there might be other javascript interfering with the printing that you haven't included here. It would help if you add all the code you used to make this (HTML and JS as well).

Comment: My page is purely HTML and CSS. The Multiple.js page has a description of how it's effects can be implemented in CSS-only and that is what I used. I have never used fiddle, but I'll try to figure that out. As far as posting the whole code, I'd like to avoid doing that if possible because it has personal information on it. Perhaps I can post a very basic version of it. Thanks for responding so fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed` ([docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)) is supposed to keep the background in a specific location even if you scroll over the top of it. Obviously, in print, you can't scroll an element...

I would instead, remove that and use `background-position: top left;` (or where ever else you want it to appear). You probably also want to set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` if you're used to the background showing in a specific location.

Also if you're running into issues with the print renderer (where simple stuff without decor like gradients is probably better) you could look into a library to do that conversion. [WkHTMLtoPDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) has been doing this for a long time.

Comment: I was looking for some kind of conversion that didn't require printing, but didn't run into WkHTMLtoPDF. I will try that and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @SahilPatel Otherwise, I dug into how multiple.js works and realized it's using a background-attachment hack to basically position the background relative to its parent. Paper essentially removes this and breaks your layout. You could resolve it by manually setting the `background-position` of each element relative to its parent. Think of it like a [CSS image sprite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS). I'd probably do that with javascript depending on your layout.